# Rails 4: Escape Not Found error for nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to escape NotFound exception for nested form associations, when there is one relation isn't found.

For example, i have

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :user_selection_criteria
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_selection_criteria, :reject_if => lambda { |t| t['brand_id'].nil? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

and

```
if @user.update_attributes user_params
  render
else
  render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

Which updates attributes, params do permit this, and everything is ok.

I use nested form, say, with those attributes.

```
user_selection_criteria_attributes[0][id]       
user_selection_criteria_attributes[0][brand_id]     
user_selection_criteria_attributes[0][_destroy]
user_selection_criteria_attributes[1][id]       
user_selection_criteria_attributes[1][brand_id]     
user_selection_criteria_attributes[1][_destroy]
user_selection_criteria_attributes[2][id]       
user_selection_criteria_attributes[2][brand_id]     
user_selection_criteria_attributes[3][_destroy]
```

etc...

Everything is OK, when i:

- Leave id blank - a new record is created
- Use id of existing record - corresponding record is updated.

But when i use non-existing record id, for example when another user already deleted this record, i get an error **Couldn't find UserSelectionCriterium with ID=13 for User with ID=12**

When i use

```
begin
  if @user.update_attributes user_params
    render
  else
    render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
escape
  render
end
```

Error is escaped, but attributes aren't saved. But that's expected.

Question: how do i squelch/escape that error, ignore that record does not exist any more, and save any other valid relations?

I.e. when nested relation with id 13 doesn't exist, but relation with id 14 exists, relation 13 is ignored and 14 is processed normally.

Comment: How likely is that to happen and how often? Personally I wouldn't bother. I would use a finder that doesn't raise an error, like `find_by(id:...)` and have return a validation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter these ids which's record does not exsited, like this(ideally, use your own code):

```
def some_params
    params.require(:user).permit(user_selection_criteria_attributes: [:id, :brand_id]).tap do |white_list|
      white_list[:user_selection_criteria_attributes].each do |key, value|
        if value[:id].present? && UserSelectionCriteria.find_by(id: value[:id]).blank?

          white_list[:user_selection_criteria_attributes].delete(key)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: You forgot ) before .tap

Thanks, that worked great.